# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 crash when opening MVC View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and ASP.NET MVC RC installed on a XP SP2 machine with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. (That's a lot of SP's in one sentence!)

I've a ASP.NET MVC project that I can edit just fine with Visual Web Developer Express.
But opening a View page in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 makes Visual Studio to crash and vanish without even giving an error message.

Now, some bloggers have proposed that either Visual Studio Power Tools of TFS Power Tools could be causing this. However, I have neither installed.

Visual Studio can be started with /SafeMode option which solves the issue. But I'd like to know if there's more elegant solution available?

Pom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft have now released a hotfix to resolve this issue.

See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16827&wa=wsignin1.0

Phil Haack elaborates here - http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/06/hotfix-for-installing-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was clearing the Native Image Cache.

go to %windir%\assembly and delete the folders that start with NativeImages.  I Have two... NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32 and NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64 because I'm running 64-bit Vista.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a few days back, and I removed all examples of Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll. I found the solution on google, and like you I'm not running PowerTools. I guess you're seeing

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A035E00) (80131506)?

I renamed all examples of that DLL and rebooted, and now I can work again, don't know what I'll do when I have to unit test SilverLight again though.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself here:

I eventually removed Visual Studio add-in called Ora. That seemed to stop MVC View related Visual Studio crashes.